# Regarding Database data deletion from tables in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I'm new to mysql. My Requirement is I have a database "sample" and there are 20 tables in it with some sample data. I want to remove all the data from all tables of that database without deleting tables or recreating them

So please help me with a solutions.

Regards
Chandu.

Answer (score 4):

Call [`TRUNCATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) on each table.